# Kotlin Version issues: The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0

Tags: kotlin, flutter-dependencies

I am building a mobile app with flutter framework and i get this error when i run "flutter build apk"

Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

I have tried updating and downgrading the Kotling version but still no way out.